# order of printf command in c

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to learn c and am just starting with watching some online videos and was trying to do this example but my results are not what I expect. This code is simply to enter a number and print out the number you entered, however I can't tell where it is going wrong.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int aNumber;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &aNumber);
    printf("you entered %d", aNumber);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

but when I run this code it should ask the user to enter a number instead it does nothing until i enter a number and the output is this:

5
Please enter a number: you entered 5

where I type in 5, press enter and then the code prints out the statement. Can anyone tell me why the ordering is going wrong. It should be

Please enter a number: 5
you entered 5

where  the "please enter a number: " pops up first then I enter 5 and so on.

Comment: if it matters im using eclipse Cpp mars IDE and MnGW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely need to flush stdout to make the output show up. To do this call `fflush(stdout)`. If you don't do this some of the output could be buffered which causes what you are seeing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int aNumber;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &aNumber);
    printf("you entered %d", aNumber);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's strange, because `scanf` usually flushes `stdout` for you... I thought.  Maybe depends on the implementation.

Comment: Does `scanf` flush `stdout` before or after returning? In this case it looks like it is potentially flushing `stdout` after reading from `stdin`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Depends on compiler implementation. Most do flust stdout when using printf, but not all.

Comment: Should be noted anyway that the getchar is useless because it will read the next character after the integer read by scanf, which will be typically the new line character used to validate the input. Removing this getchar will give the same result.

Comment: Thanks guys adding fflush fixed it, I was just confused because in the example they didn't need to use fflush.

Comment: Congrats on a 4 digit rep.

Answer (score 1):

That´s a really unusual result from such a simple program. Other people pointed out the ´fflush´, I just want to mention that ending printf with a new line also cause the buffer to flush out. so if you don´t care your input to appear one a new line, you have new way to deal with it.